# Getting push notification for calendar events in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I have integrated [Google Calendar](https://console.developers.google.com/apis) APIs with my [Chrome Extension](http://chrome://extensions/).

I need to get notification in my extension, when I schedule an calendar event from any client. How can I get this feature?

Was reading about [Google Calendar Push](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), But this pushes to a SSL certified webpage. Is it possible to receive notifications directly in the extension?

Comment: I explored a few things and able to register to the "WATCH" api, but still exploring on getting notified by the calendar via gcm. Can some body help here.

Answer (score 0):

The notifications specified for use in chrome extensions is [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications):

Use the `chrome.notifications` API to create rich notifications using templates and show these notifications to users in the system tray.

There's a [github sample](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/notifications) you can try.

Comment: Thanks @noogui, The suggested sample explains about showing the notification in chrome. But I am interested in knowing the receiving a change notification from google calendar. Can you help me in that?.